# Counting the number of ways to use stamps when the available stamps are 1,2, and 3 cents

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

My process to solve this:

Letting n = the number of total cents, I will be solving for $a_n$.

So my goal is to find $a_8$, but  before this I will have to look at the first three and try to find a pattern.

$a_1 = 1$: 1

$a_2 = 2$: 1+1  2

$a_3 = 4$: 1+1+1 1+2 2+1 3

$a_4$ is where it gets a little complicated so I counted by hand and ended up with 7: 1+1+1+1 1+2+1 1+1+2 1+3 2+1+1 2+2 3+1

This led to a pattern of $a_{n-1}$ of arrangements that start with 1, $a_{n-2}$ arrangements that start with 2 and finally $a_{n-3}$ arrangements that start with 3.

Using this same process for 5 and on, I got to $a_8$ and

$a_8 = a_7 + a_6 + a_5$ = 81.

Comment: For clarification, you do consider $1+2$ to be a different outcome than $2+1$?  Why or why not?

Comment: It was given in this problem that order matters.

Comment: If you consider them to be different, then this is related to the [tribonacci sequence](https://oeis.org/A000073) shifted some entries to the right.  Your recurrence relation is correct and a closed form solution can be found in the same manner as finding the closed form solution of the fibonacci sequence, in this case by studying the roots of the corresponding characteristic polynomial $\chi(x)=x^3-x^2-x-1$.

Comment: so if given, 1 cent, 2 cent, and 7 cent, would the $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-7} \forall n\geq 8$?

Comment: Yes, and a closed form could be found by inspecting the roots of the corresponding characteristic polynomial $x^7-x^6-x^5-1$, though admittedly those roots will be much more challenging to find.  This problem is more commonly found in literature as a domino tiling problem (*or more generally phrased a $b$-omino*), your original problem can be rephrased as "how many ways can you tile a $1\times n$ board using $1\times 1, 1\times 2$ or $1\times 3$ tiles?"

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions. For 1¢ it is $1 + z + z^2 + \dotsb = (1 - z)^{-1}$, for 2¢ it is $1 + z^2 + z^4 + \dotsb = (1 - z^2)^{-1}$, 3¢ gives $1 + z^3 + z^6 + \dotsb = (1 - z^3)^{-1}$, In all:

$\begin{align*}
   A(z)
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n \\
     &= \frac{1}{(1 - z) (1 - z^2) (1 - z^3)} \\
     &= \frac{11 + 3 z + 3 z^2}{1 - z^3}
          + \frac{1}{8 (1 + z)}
          + \frac{1}{4 (1 - z)^2}
          + \frac{1}{6 (1 - z)^3}
\end{align*}$

The last is just partial fractions, but adding terms with denominators $1 + z + z^2$ and $1 - z$ to simplify coefficient extraction. Using the generalized binomial theorem:

$\begin{align*}
  (1 - x)^{-m}
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n \binom{-m}{n} x^n \\
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n + m - 1}{m - 1} x^n
\end{align*}$

we get the coefficients:

$\begin{align*}
  a_n
    &= [z^n] A(z) \\
    &= \frac{1}{24}(11 [z^n] + 3 [z^{n - 1}] + 3 [z^{n - 2}]) \frac{1}{1 - z^3}
         + \frac{(-1)^n}{8}
         + \frac{1}{4} \binom{n + 2 - 1}{2 - 1}
         + \frac{1}{6} \binom{n + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} \\
   &= \frac{11 [n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}] + 3 [n \not\equiv 0 \pmod{3}]}{24}
        + \frac{(-1)^n}{8}
        + \frac{n^2 + 6 n + 5}{12}
\end{align*}$

Here we use Iverson's bracket: $[\phi]$ is 1 if condition $\phi$ is true, 0 if false.